# My app is compatible on my device but, when it publish on google play it says device is not compilable?

Tags: java, android

The app invokes permission of camera, SMS, flashlight, read and write SMS? 
Don't know what to do. 
Plz help.

Comment: check the manifest file, you likely have declared some hardware feature as required there, which is not available in your device

Comment: And provider the device build version. + The manifest

Comment: plz ask a proper question. With the "information" you provided we can do nothing. See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Either you declared a hardware feature like `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />` or one of the 3rd party libraries you use has max-sdk level set lower then your initial